# Inbound mail Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I want to manage my inbound emails in Alfresco the same way demonstrated in the next picture or more detailed in this [video](https://youtu.be/hH5wKZMCnH8?t=175)

[image]

How can I do that?

I'm using Alfresco 6.2 community.

Answer (score 0):

You've embedded a video of a demo for a custom solution called Alfea Correspondence Management. So the short answer is that you should contact the vendor to see if it is still available, inquire about pricing, then install it, and you're done.

If you cannot acquire the solution from that vendor and you have to implement this yourself it will take more work than can or should be described here.

At a very basic level, Alfresco can be configured to accept inbound email. But this requires senders to add Alfresco to the recipient list. Once the objects are in the repository, they are like any other nodes, so they can be queried against and presented in custom dashlets, like the one shown in your video.

I suspect the solution the vendor is showing will do more than just accept inbound emails. All of that functionality would have to be developed custom if you cannot acquire it from the vendor.